# Ubuntu screen resolution cannot be changed

Tags: nvidia, resolution, display-resolution, ubuntu-drivers

I installed  nvidia drivers manually and I rebooted my laptop after that. My screen resolution changed to really low and even after I login I cannot see taskbar and I cannot see anything other than steam desktop icon so I cannot change the resolution. Is there anyway to fix this. Please help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the super key ("Windows" key) and type "displays", then down arrow twice, then enter. That should bring up the display manager which should allow you to change the display settings.

If display manager doesn't work, then you might need to get into the Nvidia Settings Manager (it's been several year since I've dealt with Nvidia software on any of my machines, so I'm not sure what you would need to tweak there or how to get to the right options).